# Convertir timestamp a fecha en Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Necesito convertir `timestamp` a fecha con formato `DD/MM/AAAA` o algun otro formato de fecha ej: `AAAA-MM-DD`, gracias.

Comment: Nos muestras que has intentado

Comment: saludos te sugiero revisar:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql

Comment: ya probe de esta forma: to_date(to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') y me envía un error

Comment: Que error te da?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
to_char(to_timestamp(DATABASE_FIELD), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') AS creacion_curso
```

*DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI* Lo puedes reemplazar por el formato de salida que necesites.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 2):

Puede dar formato a tu salida de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT  to_char( fecha, 'YYYY-MON-DD') as fecha_fomateada from tabla;
```